# Enabled using coding for use wireless network

Tags: android, networking

I am new to android i stuck for using coding enable location and sectury in that use wireless network enabled so please tell mi how it's possible

thanks
priya naral

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered, you want to programmatically turn on Wi-Fi.

If so, first you need to add these to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>
    .
    .
    .
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
</application>
```

Then you have the ability to use `WifiManager`, so your code would look something like the following, where `this` is your application `Context`:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if(!manager.isWifiEnabled()){
    manager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```